# Inserting data into a sql query from a text box in a html form

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT
ticketDescription,ticketTimeDate,ticketCategory,ticketServerity,user.userLocation,user.userFirstNames,user.userSurname,user.userDepartment,user.userContactNumber,user.userEmailAddress
FROM ticket
LEFT JOIN ticketHistory ON
ticket.ticketID = ticketHistory.ticketID
LEFT JOIN technician ON
ticketHistory.technicianID = technician.technicianID
LEFT JOIN user ON
ticket.userID = user.userID
WHERE ticketResolved = '0'
AND technician.technicianID = '1'
```

I am trying to replace the integer where the sql query is returning results based on the technician ID. (the last line). I want to replace the '1' with a value from a text box on a html form which the user will fill in and click submit. Then the html form's action would put the value from the text box into the AND technician.technicianID = '****' where the text box's value would replace the ****.

Seems simple enough, but has completely stumped me!

Comment: it is not the right way. See some basic of php and html fom tutorial by googling

Comment: And tag your questions with the database you are actually using.  SQL Server and MySQL are two different products.

Comment: Sorry guys, completely new to this.

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: Note that your WHERE condition nullifies the outerliness of your outer join ;-)

Comment: Have you tried on of the hundreds of MySQLi/PDO tutorials that use prepared statements?

Comment: you can store your textbox result into a variable like '@input1' and you can use this variable @input1 in place of 1.

Comment: It appears I am going about this in wrong direction. Oops. Could I replace the criteria with a session variable that contains the technician ID from when they log in?

Comment: @Zafar Malik sounds exactly what I am trying to do, how would I format this within a SQL query, do I just use AND technician.technicianID = '@variable_name'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like below:

```
set @input1=1;

SELECT
ticketDescription,ticketTimeDate,ticketCategory,ticketServerity,user.userLocation,user.userFirstNames,user.userSurname,user.userDepartment,user.userContactNumber,user.userEmailAddress
FROM ticket
LEFT JOIN ticketHistory ON
ticket.ticketID = ticketHistory.ticketID
LEFT JOIN technician ON
ticketHistory.technicianID = technician.technicianID
LEFT JOIN user ON
ticket.userID = user.userID
WHERE ticketResolved = '0'
AND technician.technicianID = @input1;
```